# Java checked and unchecked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, checked, unchecked

1. If I create an exception class that extends `Exception`, will my class be checked or unchecked? I note that the subclass of `Exception` called `RuntimeException` is an unchecked exception whereas all other subclasses of 'Exception' are checked exceptions.
2. If I create an exception class that extends `RuntimeException`, can I specify that this class is checked?

Comment: Answered by https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Checked

2) No

If you extend Exception -> checked

If you extend RuntimeException -> unchecked

From documentation:

> The class {@code Exception} and any subclasses that are not also
>    * subclasses of {@link RuntimeException} are checked
>    * exceptions

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are checked unless they inherit from RuntimeException or Error

Answer (score 1):

If your class extends Exception it can throw checked exceptions.

If your class extends Error or RuntimeException it can throw unchecked exceptions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you create class that extends Exception it would be checked. You can't specify RuntimeException as checked since it is unchecked exception